# Getting a class instance after set context of the class

Tags: java, android

i was wondering how i can call a int value from the Gameview class after i do this : `setContentView(new GameView(this, this));`.
Setting a new instance like
`GameView game = new GameView(this , this );` after setting the content view will just crash my program. is there any way else to retrieve my int value?

Comment: What about creating the instance before the setContentView and reusing it ?

Comment: u meant like this?`GameView game = new GameView(this , this );` `setContentView(game);`

Comment: Offtopic: why do you have 2 parameters, both 'this' ?

Comment: i was handed over this project to refine it. And im very bad with java. so currently i have no explanation for that.

Answer (score 0):

i added a`system.gc` after the initiation of `setContentView(new GameView(this, this));` it did help to solve the crashing part. but if the codes still works prefectly after is still not proofed.